# Django Rest Framework serializing queryset fetchedn with value_list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to query a specific column from my table. I've tried doing it with this

```
team_lenDeserialized = RolesInTeam.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True).filter(academic_year_id=9).filter(deleted=0)
team_lenDict = RolesInTeamSerializer(team_lenDeserialized, many=True)
team_len = orderedDictToJSON(team_lenDict.data)
```

After that I run it through a function that converts it to JSON

```py
def orderedDictToJSON(orderedDict):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(orderedDict))
```

then I go and manipulate it further. However if I try to serialize and convert the `team_lenDeserialized` I get an error that states

```py
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user_id` on 
serializer RolesInTeamSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any 
attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'user_id'.
```

This is my model for that table

```
class RolesInTeam(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    team_id = models.IntegerField()
    role_id = models.IntegerField()
    deleted = models.IntegerField()
    academic_year_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'roles_in_team'
```

and my serializer

```
class RolesInTeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RolesInTeam
        fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'team_id', 'role_id', 'deleted', 'academic_year_id']
```

I have no clue what's happening or why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can only serialize models instances with a ModelSerializer, and `values_list()` returns a queryset of tuples, so when you try to use the serializer over the queryset, you get the error.

If you make a regular query (`team_lenDeserialized = RolesInTeam.objects.filter(academic_year_id=9).filter(deleted=0)`), you would be able to serialize `team_lenDeserialized`.

Comment: I am aware of that. However I wanna avoid fetching the entire table since, as I've said, it's gonna hit the performance at some point

Comment: @Mislav well, in that case you cannot use that serializer over the resultset you are getting since you specify the fields it should receive, and you are not provideing them.

Comment: What's the way to go around that then?

Comment: well, if you use `values()` instead of `values_list()`, you'll get a list of dicts that need no further serialization.